# Key/Value lookup in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm working with an Angular application in which I am storing some information relative to the identifying id of that information. In the angular application I need to pull information for separate identifiers and display it on the screen.

Currently, I am doing so like this:

```
var foo = [[]];

var info = {
    id: 950252,
    text: "Hello world."
};

foo[info.id] = info;
```

Which allows me to access this in AngularHTML like so:

```
{{foo[id].text}} // Hello world.
```

The problem with this is, the array will have X indecies, where X is the highest identifying value. That means in this example alone, there are 950,252 array values stored as "null". I feel like this is horrible practice.

The other idea is to store data like so:

```
var foo = [];

var info = {
    id: 950252,
    text: "Hello world."
};

foo.push(info);
```

However, with this implementation I have no idea how to access the value stored with an id of 950252, because that bit of info is going to be at a random index in the array (Whatever it was inserted at by push, which is the next available index) however I won't be able to know that index to call it via `foo[id]`

Comment: Do you want show the entire array foo on your html eventually? Or do you want to show a specific value, based on an ID you get? e.g. You say you access it in your html like: `{{foo[id].text}}`, but where does that `id` come from?

Comment: @Guinn id is a variable in my controller.

Comment: Haha well basicly PSL gave the easiest way. You could create a complicated lookup, but you can also define the array as an object. I believe your HTML way to access it remains the same

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an array use an object literal, otherwise you end up creating sparse arrays (arrays with gaps) with your first approach, and with your second approach you already noticed that lookup is not easy. With this approach instead of treating the id as index (on an array) it will be treated as key (on an object).

i.e

change

```
var foo = [];
```

to

```
var foo = {};
//....
foo[info.id] = info;
```

If you really want to retain an array of object and still want to maintain a separate hash you could do so either by creating another variable that holds it or by adding a property on the array object itself, for example:

```
var foo = [];
foo.hash = {};
//
foo.hash[info.id] = (arr.push(info) - 1); //Store the hash as id and its current value as its current index. But remember to maintain it. Also use proper loop iteration mechanism to iterate through the array. If you are adding deleting items from array this is not a suitable approach as you would need to maintain the has indices as well.

//provided the id you can get the value as:
var infoSelected = foo[foo.hash[id]];
```

*Side note: You may have to associate this object to scope or controller instance depending on how you are associating the bindings.*

Comment: So, this is basically, an array... but.... not? (Similar to a Map<> in Java, I guess)

Comment: @Christian.tucker It is not an array. It is an object, Arrays are also objects with special properties. But this is just object literal and syntax `obj[somekey]` is property accessor/setter [via bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).